# CQL syntax error: "mismatched input 'and' expecting ')' "

Tags: cassandra, where-clause, cql

I am executing the below query :

```
SELECT * FROM test
WHERE (
    Column11 in ('Value1','Value2','Vlaue3')
    AND Column12 in ('Value11','Value22','Vlaue32')
    AND Column13 = 'Value99'
);
```

This is giving below error :

```
mismatched input 'and' expecting ')' (...,'Value3')  [and]...)
```

But when I am executing above query with out external braces, its working fine.

```
SELECT * FROM test 
WHERE Column11 in ('Value1','Value2','Vlaue3')  
    AND Column12 in ('Value11','Value22','Vlaue32') 
    AND Column13 = 'Value99' ;
```

Is there any way to execute first query ? Because I want to add multiple clauses, OR separated, and prepare a big query.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49872417/cassandra-subquery-alternate Cassandra doesnt support this sub queries.

Comment: ...Thank  You   .... @Rafee

Comment: But that's not the same problem, @Rafee. This one is just parentheses enclosing conditions forming the where clause. It's not a sub-query.

Comment: @R_S_C It could be because of clustering of column https://docs.datastax.com/en/cql-oss/3.x/cql/cql_reference/cqlSelect.html#cqlSelect__comparing-clustering-columns

Comment: Depending on the size of the expected data payload and number of nodes in the cluster, unless `column13` is a partition key, this query will probably time-out.

Comment: May be you are using reserved keyword as column name. My reply on same kind of exception at https://stackoverflow.com/a/71903497/556540

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> This one is just parentheses enclosing conditions forming the where clause.

Subquery or not, the CQL parser does not allow for extra parens.

> I want to add multiple clauses, OR separated, and prepare a big query.

Due to Cassandra's underlying engineering choices with regard to data distribution and read path, `OR` is not a valid CQL keyword.

Cassandra requires you to model tables based on the anticipated query patterns.  When you run a query, the goal should be to ensure that it can be served by a single node in the cluster.  `OR` based logic tends to be more open-ended, and not focused on precise key values.

**tl;dr;**

CQL != SQL.  This sounds to me like more of a use case for Postgres or MariaDB.